# User login issue after WordPress update

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have upgraded WordPress from 2.2 to 4.3.1 manually and also updated all the related plugins, but after update WordPress, the user of my site is not able to login.

When user puts its email id and password and after clicking to the submit button the page gets redirected to wp-login.php with error message invalid user name even with correct user name and password, even after register the user's are not able to login. In general after login the users are suppose to go their profile page.

I had tried every possible solutions.

1. adding redirection code in my function.php
2. Changing login password.
3. custom login code instead to send in wp-login.php
4. Renaming my current theme then manually update with fresh WordPress

In general after login the users are suppose to go, to their profile page.

Nothing works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There might be the plugin issue. Did you tried deactivating the plugins and see if users can logged in after deactivating the plugins. Try deactivating the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that your wp-settings.php matches this one?

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-settings.php

Specifically line 122 that requires session.php, and that session.php also matches

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/session.php

If you still getting issue.

Try to reference from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-login-after-400-update)

Comment: Hi Yatin Khullar,  i tired your given solutions and follow the link also,but didn't work either.

Comment: I had also deactivated all the plugins but still this issue arises.

Comment: try to turn on debug mode and see what error you are getting

Comment: I resolved the issue actually problem was in wp-login.php having some functions missing.Any ways thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

After WordPress3.7 , it automatic updates the WordPress and it won't allow admin or anybody to login so This post guides you to ix it

http://onl9class.com/solved-cant-login-after-wordpress-update/